# prove that every graph on $n$ vertices, $n\geq 4$, with more than $2n^{3/2}$ edges has girth of at most 4

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, extremal-graph-theory

> prove that every graph on $n$ vertices, $n\geq 4$, with more than $2n^{3/2}$ edges has girth of at most 4

Given the fact that every simple graph that satisfies $\sum_{v\in V} {{d(v)}\choose{2}} > (m-1){{n}\choose 2}$
contains $K_{2,m}$ how can you prove this?
I mean for $n<18$ it follows that ${{n}\choose 2} < 2n^{3/2}$ so it seems weird it would even have this many edges.

Thanks.

Comment: Very roughly, the average vertex has more than $4 \sqrt n$ edges coming out of it.  Pick a vertex with lots of edges.  It connects to more than $4 \sqrt n$ other vertices.  If any two of them are connected, you have a $3$ cycle.  If two of them connect to the same other vertex you have a $4$ cycle.  If they were average you would need $4 \sqrt n (4 \sqrt n-1) \gt n$ vertices for them to connect to.  There is a lot of margin here, about a factor $16$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [graph theory problem - containing $K_{2,m}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3179562/graph-theory-problem-containing-k-2-m)

Comment: @Aqua I didn't understand the part where you used Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, can't really see what you were using it on..